# Excel Formula convert to C#

Tags: c#, excel, formula

Im new to c# but trying to run this formula from a WPF.

```
=(BIN2DEC(RIGHT(DEC2BIN(MOD(INT(A1/16777216), 256),8), 3)) * 16777216) + (MOD(INT(A1/65536), 256) * 65536) + (MOD(INT(A1/256), 256) * 256) + MOD(A1,256)
```

started to try and work through but think im not even close....
if anyone has any pointers.....

```
decimal A1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
A1 = (A1 / 16777216);
A1 = decimal.Truncate(A1);
A1 = decimal.Remainder(Left, Right);
Convert.ToByte(A1);
String Number = A1.ToString();
Number.Reverse();
Number.Remove(3);
Number.Reverse();
A1 = Convert.ToByte(Number);
```

and so on....

----------------- UPDATE----------------------------------

Sorry, if it's clearer im trying to achieve this..

A 32bit number should translate into an 8 or 9 digit (27bit binary) number. If a 9 digit decimal number is produced, you will need to drop the most significant decimal digit to show the number that I want.

Examples: 
467597668 converts to 64944484

705313524 converts to 34224884

4294967295 converts to 134217727

Im trying this now but get an incorrect number ?

---

```
        int A1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
        A1 /= 16777216;
        A1 &= 7; 
        A1 *= 16777216;
        int A2 = (((A1 >> 16) & 255) << 16);
        int A3 = (((A1 >> 8) & 255) << 8);
        int A4 = (A1 & 255);
        textBox2.Text = (A1+A2+A3+A4).ToString();
```

---

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @Ramhound I believe it was "if anyone has any pointers.....". You should try reading, it's useful.

Comment: @BrianGraham - I feel that asking for vague pointers is not a valid SO question.  He does not explain what he does not understand.  All he has to do is do the order of operations.  He can skip the INT method.  He didn't even provide a complete sample.

Comment: i've updated if it helps... not sure why the number is not correct but starting to understand the bit operator syntax

Answer (score 3):

Since you have a nice integer types and bit operations in C#, you do not have to jump through the same hoops as in Excel.

Here is how you convert the initial part `(BIN2DEC(RIGHT(DEC2BIN(MOD(INT(A1/16777216), 256),8), 3)) * 16777216)`:

```
int A1 = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
A1 /= 16777216; // This also truncates the result; INT(A1/16777216)
A1 &= 7; // This takes the last three bits of the number: BIN2DEC(RIGHT(DEC2BIN(MOD(A1,8),3))
A1 *= 16777216; // A1 * 16777216
```

`(MOD(INT(A1/65536), 256) * 65536)`, `(MOD(INT(A1/256), 256) * 256)`, and `MOD(A1,256)` are even simpler:

```
(((A1 >> 16) & 255) << 16)
(((A1 >> 8) & 255) << 8)
(A1 & 255)
```

`>>` means "shift (binary representation) to the right"; `<<` means "shift (binary representation) to the left". Shifting by one is equivalent to multiplying or dividing by two in the same way that shifting a decimal number is equivalent to multiplying or int-dividing by ten.

`&` means bitwise `AND`. 255 is a number with the last eight bits set to one; AND-ing with it keeps the last eight bits of the original number.

**EDIT** : Here is a corrected version of your re-write that returns the right result:

```
int A0 = 467597668;
int A1 = A0 / 16777216;
A1 &= 7;
A1 *= 16777216;
int A2 = (((A0 >> 16) & 255) << 16);
int A3 = (((A0 >> 8) & 255) << 8);
int A4 = (A0 & 255);
Console.WriteLine(A1 + A2 + A3 + A4);
```

Comment: That is because you are using `A1` after it has been modified. I added `A0` to mean "the original A1", see the edit to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some bit operations to me based on constants and operations. In C# you should simply use bit-wise "and" (`&`), "or" (`|`) and shifts (`<<`, `>>`) to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This should help, from what I gather,

```
RIGHT(DEC2BIN(MOD(INT(A1/16777216), 256),8), 3)) * 16777216
```

is equivalent to

```
(((a1 / 16777216) % 256) & 7) * 16777216
```

You should be able to use this to derive the other 3 components.

Comment: using the above im getting 50331648